# Using the same code for different target in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, module

I want to use the same code for different target in Xcode. I am able to create the target using the Duplicate method and then I am able to change scheme name as well.

Now the real scenario comes, I want to be use my code in centralised way like for new target, I don't want to copy and paste the Main.storyboard and xib as well, so, ideally what would happen, if I would change anything in one place, all target would share that.But the issue comes, that ``ViewController`in`Main.Storyboard` holds the master project "module" so, when I run the child target, it could not run.

Comment: What do you mean by `ViewController in Main.Storyboard holds the master project "module"`? Have you tried selecting both targets for `Main.Storyboard` on the right utilities panel under target Membership?

Comment: @Xiangxin.. Yes, all files have target memberships for two targets... my question is for the module.. module in storyboard files are not changing.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by `master project "module"`? screenshot?

Answer (score 5):

You can open Utilities panel, select File inspector tab and mark necessary targets for every file you want to share.
See attached image as a reference.
[image: targets]

Answer (score 4):

Of-course you can do it. you can use single code/file for multiple target and/or single target, according to your requirement.

[Apple document for the same](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html)

**Have a look at these snapshots:**

> **For existing file in your project follow these steps to assign multiple targets**
>   Select your file ▶ Utilities window ▶ File Inspector ▶ Target
>   Membership ▶ Select target according to your requirement for source
>   file usage

[image: > Test]

> **Create new file with multiple targets**
>   Menu >> New File >> Select File Type >> Assign File Name >> Next >>
>   Select targets for your file.

[image: x]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the Module and select `Inherit From Target` instead?

[image]

Comment: Great... This is what I amy be looking at... However in Xcode 8.2.1.. it does not have the option.. but in 8.3 it has.. do you know what should we do in 8.2.1

Comment: I forgot what it looked like in 8.2.1. But it's definitely possible. Do you have a screenshot by any chance ?